# Berks upload not working in ChefDK Berkshelf

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, chefdk

berks upload -d gives:

```
There was an error connecting to the Chef Server

Chef Development Kit Version: 2.4.17
berks version: 6.3.1
```

Here's my config.json

```
{
    "chef": {
        "chef_server_url": "<insert Chef server url here>"
                },
    "ssl": {
        "verify": false 
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
    :~/code/chef-repo/cookbooks/myhaproxy$ berks upload -d
I, [2018-03-10T07:34:42.966812 #6015]  INFO -- : Checking if lockfile is trusted
D, [2018-03-10T07:34:42.966938 #6015] DEBUG -- : Checking myhaproxy (>= 0.0.0)
D, [2018-03-10T07:34:42.967738 #6015] DEBUG -- : Using 'chefignore' at '/home/sid/code/chef-repo/cookbooks/myhaproxy/chefignore'
D, [2018-03-10T07:34:43.025571 #6015] DEBUG -- :   Detected there is a cached cookbook
D, [2018-03-10T07:34:43.026271 #6015] DEBUG -- :   Checking transitive dependencies for myhaproxy (0.1.0)
D, [2018-03-10T07:34:43.026367 #6015] DEBUG -- :     Checking haproxy (= 2.0.0)
D, [2018-03-10T07:34:43.026593 #6015] DEBUG -- :     Checking transitive dependencies for haproxy (2.0.0)
D, [2018-03-10T07:34:43.026667 #6015] DEBUG -- :       Already checked - skipping
I, [2018-03-10T07:34:44.551086 #6015]  INFO -- : Uploading cookbooks
D, [2018-03-10T07:34:44.551238 #6015] DEBUG -- :   No names given, using all cookbooks
I, [2018-03-10T07:34:44.557384 #6015]  INFO -- : Starting upload
There was an error connecting to the Chef Server
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/lib/berkshelf.rb:165:in `ridley_connection'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/lib/berkshelf/uploader.rb:50:in `upload'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/lib/berkshelf/uploader.rb:37:in `run'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/lib/berkshelf/berksfile.rb:597:in `upload'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/lib/berkshelf/cli.rb:205:in `upload'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/lib/berkshelf/cli.rb:49:in `dispatch'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/lib/berkshelf/cli.rb:25:in `execute!'
    /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/bin/berks:5:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/bin/berks:255:in `load'
    /usr/bin/berks:255:in `<main>'
```

Comment: There was an error connecting to the Chef Server
 /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/lib/berkshelf.rb:165:in `ridley_connection'
 /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-6.3.1/lib/berkshelf/uploader.rb:50:in `upload'

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: You need to show the actual error, not just say that there was one.

Comment: @slashpai Not yet.

Comment: @coderanger Please see now, I've included the error message.

Comment: Do other `knife` commands work? If do, delete your berkshelf config.json and try it again.

Comment: @coderanger Yes, they do. I followed your advice but still no luck,

Answer (score 0):

Your problem likely lies in your knife.rb. Try running `knife status`.

Comment: knife status works too:
6298 hours ago, oelol, oracle 7.2.
1848 hours ago, trusty, ubuntu 14.04.
280 hours ago, xenial, ubuntu 16.04.
271 hours ago, trusty64, ubuntu 16.04.
271 hours ago, xenial2, ubuntu 16.04.